# Maintain page content after js onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been having a hard time thinking how I can make the page stay where it is after submitting a form where there is a js onchange.

This is my dropdown where I would select between daily sales and monthly sales.

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <select name="sales" onchange="javascript: submit()">
   <option>Select an option</option>
   <option>Daily Sales</option>
   <option>Monthly Sales</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

This is the php code where I will output some code with another onchange.

```
<?php
$sales =  isset($_POST['sales']) ? $_POST['sales'] : '';
if(isset($sales)) {

if($sales == 'Daily Sales') {
    echo '<input type="date" name="daily" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
    echo 'Some tables here';
}
else{
  echo '<input type="date" name="monthly" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
  echo 'Some tables here';
}
}
?>
```

Now, my problem is that when I click, for example, Daily Sales and it show the daily sales and on the daily sales, when I use the input type that has an onchange in it, the daily sales disappears. How can I do it other than making separate php files for daily and monthly sales and just href it on the dropdown? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question - however I see an error that may be related to your problem. You html `option` tags should have a value, i.e. `value="Daily Sales"` - which you can then access via the `$_POST` array in your PHP

Comment: If you use `onchange()` it will try to submit as soon as you type into it because it will have changed... Try removing that experimentally and using a `submit` button and a form.